# Program to encrypt / decrypt text string in Assembly MIPS

Tags: string, encryption, mips, mars-simulator

I want to create a program that reads in input a string of characters, and through a predefined action (I was thinking of a sum with an integer randomly generated) encrypts the string by returning the encrypted string and the key to decode it in a second moment.

Could you give me any suggestions on how to treat the string?

I would like to do so :

```
li $v0,8
la $a0,buffer
li $a1,1024
syscall

move $s7,$a0
```

This is the code to read the string.
After that I want to do:

```
add $t0,$s5,$s3
```

When I add a random generated integer to the register contain the string.

After knowing the values ​​of the random number and the sum, I can again get the original string with a subtraction.

Is it a proper method?

Comment: ["Schneier's Law"](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2011/04/schneiers_law.html): Anyone, from the most clueless amateur to the best cryptographer, can create an algorithm that he himself can't break.

Answer (score 2):

That depends somewhat on the purpose of the encryption. As I understand this, the approach you're suggesting is basically a form of a Caesar Cipher. While this will protect your string to some degree against casual observers, it will definitely *not* be suitable for serious security purposes. It is subject to brute-force attacks, known-plaintext and chosen-plaintext attacks, and frequency analysis.

The idea behind a brute-force attack is that, for any given string of a reasonable length, there will almost always be exactly one shift that will make the string make sense, so an attacker could repeatedly try different shifts until he found the one that made the string make sense. The first shift that makes the string make sense is is *almost certainly* the correct shift.

If you're doing a "classical" Caesar cipher (e.g. C = A, D = B, E = C, etc.), there are only 25 possible shifts, so on average an attacker could guess the plaintext in 12.5 guesses (and 25 guesses in the worst case). In a scheme like yours you'd have to use a very large range of enormous numbers in order to be able to defend against this even slightly. For example, if you were only doing shifts of between 1 - 100 an attacker could reconstruct the plaintext in an average of 50 guesses (and 100 guesses in the worst case), which is obviously not a defense against a motivated attacker, especially since this task lends itself to easy parallelization. Assuming I did my math right, even if you had a trillion possible shifts and it took 100 operations to do and test a particular shift, you could try all of them in under 7 seconds on an Intel i7 if I did my math right and, on average, it would take less than 3.5 seconds to find the correct answer using brute force.

The idea behind frequency analysis is that your text retains the same statistical characteristics as the host language. For example, in English the most common letter is "e," so if you find the most common letter in your ciphertext it probably corresponds to "e." You can then work out how much you shifted the string to get that particular output. For example, if "g" is the most frequent letter in the ciphertext, you can guess that g = e and that they therefore must have shifted the text over by two.

A known-plaintext attack is where an attacker has an example of both the plaintext and its corresponding ciphertext and they can use that information to reconstruct what the key must have been. A chosen-plaintext attack is basically the same thing except that the attacker gets to choose which plaintext he sees the corresponding ciphertext for. (Note that this is only a problem if you're reusing keys, especially if you're doing so in a predictable manner; if you never reuse keys reconstructing the key for the known/chosen plaintext won't give the attacker any information about the key you used for other messages).

I've never tried doing this in assembly language to tell the truth but if you want good security you might want to consider [AES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard). If you're really interested in simplicity of implementation and are willing to go with something less secure, you might also go with [XTEA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XTEA).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have to made an assembly mips program for a project, and I can do all I want. I would like to create a program that hides a string, but nothing serious just a demonstration of knowing how to manage the mips assembly programming . Encryption is a topic that has always intrigued me, but with my actually skills I can't do much more than something that can be easily violated unfortunately.